# EC2 not booting because of mount - no logs

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-ec2, mount, ubuntu-16.04, amazon-ebs

I have an EC2 hosted Ubuntu 16.04 server which doesn't boot. When I look at the logs in the Amazon console i only get a black screen.

When I mount the disk to another server I have the following items in fstab:

```
LABEL=cloudimg-rootfs   /        ext4   defaults,discard        0 0
LABEL=www /home xfs defaults,noatime,nofail 0 2
```

I cannot find any entries in /var/log/syslog or anywhere else that would indicate a mounting error, but that may just be my lack of knowledge in this specific area.

However when I remove the second line from /etc/fstab the server boots. Once it is running I can then mount the disk with:

```
mount /dev/xvdf1 /home
```

I have also tried this line in fstab:

```
/dev/xvdf1 /home xfs defaults,noatime,nofail 0 2
```

but I get the same results.

Comment: Have you tried to run an `xfs_check` on the file system when you have it running?